# Unequal equilibrium arrows with overhead text

Tags: arrows, mhchem

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[\text{Hexokinase}] + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+} \\
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>> + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+}
\end{document}
```

See the resulting Latex output, and compare.  In [1] the difference between the two arrows of the unequal equilibrium sign becomes less perceptible because the sign has been stretched by the text.  Compare to the same sign without the text [2].  I want the the differences between the upper and lower arrows to be exacerbated a bit more.  How can I achieve this in LaTEX?

Answer (score 8):

Another answer because I misunderstood your question.  Digging around in the source code there are several macros which affect the length of the arrows.

From `mhchem.sty` we have

```
\newcommand*\mhchem@xlongrightshortleftharpoons[2][]{\mathrel{%
  \sbox{\mhchem@arrows@box}%
    {$\mkern9mu\ext@arrow 3399\mhchem@leftharpoondownfill@%
     {#1}{\hphantom{#2}\mkern-6mu\mkern-12mu}$}%
  \rlap{\protect\raisebox{-.22ex}{\usebox{\mhchem@arrows@box}}}%     
  \protect\raisebox{.22ex}{$\ext@arrow 3399\mhchem@rightharpoonupfill@%
    {\hphantom{\usebox{\mhchem@arrows@box}}\mkern-6mu}{#2}$}%
  }}
```

It's basically a front end to `amsmath`'s `\ext@arrow` macro:

```
\def\ext@arrow#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \mathrel{\mathop{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#5\displaystyle}%
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{\m@th
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern#3mu{#6}\mkern#4mu$}%
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern#3mu{#7}\mkern#4mu$}%
      \copy\z@
    }%
    \hbox to\wd\tw@{\unhbox\z@}}%
  \limits
    \@ifnotempty{#7}{^{\if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
                       #7\if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi}}%
    \@ifnotempty{#6}{_{\if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
                       #6\if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi}}}%
}
```

So playing around with the arguments to `\ext@arrow` in lines 3-4 will affect the length of the lower arrow.  I could not grok the `\ext@arrow` code enough to figure out how.

Instead I tried the option of drawing arrows with `pgf`.  You have to put

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\mhchemoptions{arrows=pgf}
```

in the preamble.  Then the relevant macro is:

```
\newcommand*\mhchem@longrightshortleftharpoons@pgf[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%
    \draw[use as bounding box] (0,0) (#1,1ex);
    \draw[cap=round, join=round, line width=0.09ex]
        (0.0cm,0.575ex+0.22ex) -- ++(#1,0cm) arc (250:198:0.9ex);  
    \draw[cap=round, join=round, line width=0.09ex]
        (#1+0.5em-1em,0.575ex-0.22ex) -- (0.5em,0.575ex-0.22ex) arc (70:18:0.9ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
```

From this you can see that the bottom arrow is 1em shorter than the top one.  To make it even shorter, change the last line to something like:

```
(#1-0.75em,0.575ex-0.22ex) -- (0.75em,0.575ex-0.22ex) arc (70:18:0.9ex);
```

This will make the bottom arrow 1.5em shorter.

To make this configurable, define a key and invoke it.  Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\mhchemoptions{arrows=pgf}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\mhchem@shortarrow@reduction}
\define@key{mhchem}{shortarrowreduction}{\setlength{\mhchem@shortarrow@reduction}{#1}}
\renewcommand*\mhchem@longrightshortleftharpoons@pgf[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%
    \draw[use as bounding box] (0,0) (#1,1ex);
    \draw[cap=round, join=round, line width=0.09ex]
        (0.0cm,0.575ex+0.22ex) -- ++(#1,0cm) arc (250:198:0.9ex);  
    \draw[cap=round, join=round, line width=0.09ex]
       % was: (#1+0.5em-1em,0.575ex-0.22ex) -- (0.5em,0.575ex-0.22ex) arc (70:18:0.9ex);
        (#1-\the\mhchem@shortarrow@reduction,0.575ex-0.22ex) 
        -- (\the\mhchem@shortarrow@reduction,0.575ex-0.22ex) arc (70:18:0.9ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\mhchemoptions{shortarrowreduction=0.5em}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent%
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[\text{Hexokinase}] + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+} \\
   {\mhchemoptions{shortarrowreduction=2em}
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[\text{Hexokinase}] + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+}} \\
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Comment: Go TikZ! (and some more to get to 15 characters)

Comment: Thank you - very good sir.
For a novice like me though, that is a touch daunting being somewhat of a hacky - though clever - way of going about it...
Isn't there an easier, officially supported way?  Perhaps some package supports it?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the packages author, or read te source code. There didn't appear to be an elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using (my own) [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula). It provides the option `arrow-ratio=<num>` where `<num>` should be a value between `0` and `1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[Hexokinase] "glucose~6-phosphate" + ADP + H+}

\ch[arrow-ratio=.2]{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[Hexokinase] "glucose~6-phosphate" + ADP + H+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the quotation marks around `"glucose~6-phosphate"` prevent it from being treated as a formula.

Answer (score 4):

A good trick is the `\phantom` command which typesets things invisibly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[\text{Hexokinase}] + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+} \\
   \ce{CH2OH + ATP <=>>[\phantom{\text{Hexokinase}}] + \text{glucose 6-phosphate} + ADP + H+}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TY, that was insightful Matthew.  However my question was a little different; my apologies for not being clearer.  What I meant to ask was how do I make the lower arrow in the equilibrium sign much smaller, to emphasise the lopsidedness of the equilibrium?